# Flutter - Read text file from assets

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a text file (.txt) that I'd like to be an asset that I can scan in later.

In the pubspec.yaml, I've made sure that:

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - res/my_file.txt
```

exists. The file resides in the `res/` folder that I made, on the same level as `lib/android/` and `ios/`

I'm trying to read the file from a custom class, not a widget.

According to the documentation, I'm to use this import:

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;
```

and start reading like so:

```
/// Assumes the given path is a text-file-asset.
Future<String> getFileData(String path) async {
  return await rootBundle.loadString(path);
}
```

And to get the actual data, do:

```
String data = await getFileData(fileName);
```

However, when I use a `fileName` like `'assets/res/my_file.txt'`, I get an error: `Unable to load asset: assets/res/my_file.txt`.

It's also worth noting that I'm trying to do this from a unit test. Any ideas on how to properly do this? Thanks!

Comment: Does it work fine when you're not in a unit test?

Comment: Nope. I tested in a basic app, didn't work.

Comment: It's worth noting that after I did get it working when not unit testing, I still couldn't succeed in unit tests. I would consistently get `unable to load asset`.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The folder name "assets" isn't magically added. Update your `pubspec.yaml` to include the full path to the asset.

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/res/my_file.txt
```

Comment: Thank you. My folder needed to be `assets/res/my_file.txt`, my pubspec.yaml needed `assets/res/my_file.txt`, and my path needed to be `assets/res/my_file.txt`.

Comment: you can just mention ```assets/res/``` it will give reference to all files in ```/res``` directory,This is helpful when you have multiple files in the same directory instead of giving path to each file originally answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/53662580/8253662

Answer (score 187):

Here is a fuller answer for future visitors.

### Create an assets folder

Create an assets folder in your project's root folder. In Android Studio you can right click the Project outline and go to **New > Directory**.

[image: assets]

You can create another subfolder for text files in `assets` if you like. But if you do, you have to include the relative path in pubspec.yaml. See below.

### Add your text file to the new folder

You can just copy your text file into the `assets` directory. The relative path of `my_file.txt`, for example, would be `assets/my_file.txt`.

### Register the assets folder in pubspec.yaml

Open the pubspec.yaml file that is in the root of your project.

Add an assets subsection to the flutter section like this:

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/my_file.txt
```

If you have multiple files that you want to include, then you can leave off the file name and just use the directory name (include the final /):

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/
```

### Get the text in code

You can use the global `rootBundle` to get the text file asset:

```
import 'dart:async' show Future;
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;

Future<String> loadAsset() async {
  return await rootBundle.loadString('assets/my_text.txt');
}
```

Or if you have the BuildContext (inside a widget) you can use DefaultAssetBundle. This is recommended because it allows switching asset bundles at runtime, which is useful for multilingual assets.

```
Future<String> loadAsset(BuildContext context) async {
  return await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString('assets/my_text.txt');
}
```

### See also

- [Loading text assets](https://flutter.io/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images#loading-text-assets)
- [How to include images in your app](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53752071/3681880)

Answer (score 6):

In my opinion, in order to load a js file into a flutter, you should consider it as a text file and load it properly. So, you need to add the file to assets folder, add into a pubspec file, then load it. read the full answer here

Second, you used evalJavascript. this function can be used in many different situations. but it will work only if you have a view panel.

Check below example:

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_webview_plugin/flutter_webview_plugin.dart';

main() async {
  String jsCode = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/javascript.js');

  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: LunchWebView(jsCode),
  ));
}

class LunchWebView extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  LunchWebView(this.text);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final FlutterWebviewPlugin flutterWebviewPlugin = FlutterWebviewPlugin();
    flutterWebviewPlugin.launch('https://www.google.com');
    flutterWebviewPlugin.evalJavascript(text);
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned the code below 'folder name ' can be given 'assets' if referring to the asset folder or any other directory (ex-custom_widget etc) within the project

```
 void loadAsset() async {
    await rootBundle.loadString('folder_name/custom_button.dart').then((value) =>
        print(value));
  }
```