# Flutter: how to load file for testing

Tags: testing, intellij-idea, readfile, flutter

File can be read from the directory relative to the dart script file, simply as `var file = new File('./fixture/contacts.json')`.

However the file cannot be read flutter test running inside IDE.

[Loading as resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44816042/flutter-read-text-file-from-assets) (it is not, since I do not want to bundle the test data file in the app) also does not work in test.

What is a good way to read file in flutter (for both command line test and IDE test)?

Running `flutter test` is very fast. However testing inside Intellij IDE is ver slow, but it can set debug breakpoint and step into and view variables. So both testing is very useful.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Just had a go at this and it's easier than you might expect.

First, create a folder that lives in the same directory than your tests are. For example, I created a folder called **test_resources**.

[image: Test resources folder structure.]

Then, let's say we have the following JSON file for testing purposes.

**test_resources/contacts.json**

```
{
  "contacts": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Seth Ladd"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Eric Seidel"
    }
  ]
}
```

**test/load_file_test.dart**

We could use it for our test like so:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';

void main() {
  test('Load a file', () async {
    final file = new File('test_resources/contacts.json');
    final json = jsonDecode(await file.readAsString());
    final contacts = json['contacts'];

    final seth = contacts.first;
    expect(seth['id'], 1);
    expect(seth['name'], 'Seth Ladd');

    final eric = contacts.last;
    expect(eric['id'], 2);
    expect(eric['name'], 'Eric Seidel');
  });
}
```

Comment: Is it just me or this structure doesn't work when running `flutter test`? Works in IDE though. Anyone set up for working in both: command-line and IDE?

Comment: @IkarPohorský take a look at Grahambo's answer. I had similar issue to you and his answer fixed it for me.

Comment: I prefer create resources directory inside test directory. In this way I can get the resource file with this path test/resources/contacts.json and I can keep all the test files insid test.

Comment: @liroKrankka above method works for mobile & desktop but what about loading json file for flutter-web as 'dart:io' doesn't support browser to access disk system.

Comment: For me this is not working ```FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = 'test_resources/contacts.json' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)```

Answer (score 12):

I encountered this same issue today. My tests passed in my IDE (Android Studio) but failed on CI. I found that the IDE wanted a non-relative path but `flutter test` wants a relative path. I think this is a bug and I'll be looking for the right place to report it. However, I found a crude work around for the meantime. Basically, I have a function which tries both ways to specify the file path..

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

Future<Map<String, dynamic>> parseRawSample(String filePath,
    [bool relative = true]) async {
  filePath = relative ? "test_data/src/samples/raw/$filePath" : filePath;

  String jsonString;
  try {
    jsonString = await File(filePath).readAsString();
  } catch (e) {
    jsonString = await File("../" + filePath).readAsString();
  }
  return json.decode(jsonString);
}
```

much of that code is specific to my situation, but I think others could probably adapt this work around for their purposes.

Comment: Try running `flutter test test`. No need for relative path.

Comment: I had the same problem, for me it works with `flutter test test`.

Answer (score 7):

i created an util because vscode and command line test base path is different

https://github.com/terryx/flutter-muscle/blob/master/github_provider/test/utils/test_path.dart

this is how i use it

https://github.com/terryx/flutter-muscle/blob/master/github_provider/test/services/github_test.dart#L13

---

Another way is to specify exact test path in command line

```
$ flutter test test
```

Answer (score 5):

A simple solution would be

```
import 'dart:io';

String fixture(String name) => File('test/fixtures/$name').readAsStringSync();
```

`test` folder is at the same level as the `lib` folder, and you can access the fixture like this:  `String fileContent = fixture('contacts.json')`

after that typically convert `fileContent` to `Map` object with `jsonDecode` from `dart:convert` and then map this converted object to your desired model which typically has `myModel.fromJson(Map onvertedJson)` method.

You can generate your model from JSON responses with [json to dart android studio plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12562-jsontodart-json-to-dart-) or use online converter tools like [this online JSON converter](https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/)

Answer (score 4):

The current directory is always the project root in Flutter 2.0 
So you can now read files with the same code on the command line and in the IDE.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/74622

Answer (score 3):

Just use the `Directory.current.path` and you are good to go:

```dart
import 'dart:io';


// Set the absolute path for your file
final path = '${Directory.current.path}/test/example.json'; 
final json = await File(path).readAsString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just put your test files in two places (I know it is not a good practice to have the same data in two places). Let's say I want to have data.json file to be opened in code under tests with `final file = File(dataFilename)`, then dataFilename will be 'test_resources/data.json'. If test is executed from Android Studio, test_resources is a folder in project root. If tests are executed from command line test_resources is a folder in test folder. So placing the file in both places will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just copying the solution from [Flocbit](https://github.com/flocbit): https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20907#issuecomment-557634184

```
String fixture(String name) {
   var dir = Directory.current.path;
   if (dir.endsWith('/test')) {
     dir = dir.replaceAll('/test', '');
   }
   return File('$dir/test/fixtures/$name').readAsStringSync();
}
```

Works great!

Answer (score 0):

Further clarification to Danilo's answer,

1. Put the file in test folder

[image]

2. Use 'Directory.current.path' as follows

   ```
   import 'dart:io';

       test('submit pdf in happy path', () async {

       final path = '${Directory.current.path}/test/dummy.pdf';



        // rest of the test test code
       });
   ```

Answer (score -3):

You can use **`DefaultAssetBundle`**,

final response = DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString('assets/file_name.json');

Comment: DefaultAssetBundle is undefined for me :/