# Flutter integration test - how to load a JSON file?

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

I am writing a Flutter integration test with a mock client that returns a JSON response for each of the REST endpoints my app calls.
These JSON responses are stored in separate JSON files, but I am unable to access the files when the test is running.

I've tried loading the files by creating and reading a new file object. [Flutter: how to load file for testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45780255/flutter-how-to-load-file-for-testing) but it could never find the file.
I also tried putting my JSON files into assets. This worked, but also resulted in the test JSON files being bundled when I built the APK.

Simplified Mock Client:

```
MockClient integrationMockClient = MockClient((request) async {
  switch (request.url.toString()) {
    case 'https://staging.company.com/api/123':
      return Response(readJsonfile('myJsonFile.json'), 200);
```

Simplified integration test main function - passes mock client in. `test_driver/app.dart`

```
void main() async {
  enableFlutterDriverExtension();
  final app = await initializeApp(
    integrationMockClient
  );
  runApp(app);
}
```

When I try and read a file it can never find it. Possible because flutterDriver runs the 'real app' with no access to files stored in test directories.

How can I access a JSON file from an integration test without it being bundled in production code/APK?

Comment: Have you found the solution?

Comment: Sadly no. I implemented a dodgy workaround by storing the JSON in a dart string 
`const String successJson = '{"value": 5, "Name": "test"}'`

Comment: Haha, I did the same thing after unsuccessful research :D

Comment: Is there any workaround that came up in the last 4 month, I really on the JSON I'm loading in...?

Comment: The accepted answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45780255/flutter-how-to-load-file-for-testing has an additional relevant answer below it, https://stackoverflow.com/a/57086750/6668797, which might address "*but it could never find the file*" unless you are more specific about your issue.

Comment: @TWL above method works for mobile & desktop but what about loading json file for flutter-web as 'dart:io' doesn't support browser to access disk system

Answer (score 1):

Put JSON into *String* variable, like this. `const String objectJson = """{JSON}""";`

Wrap your JSON with a triple quotation mark """

and use it on integration tests, instead of reading it from a file

Answer (score 0):

I encountered similar issues accessing file resources using `flutter driver` for integration tests. What I did as a workaround was to parse the JSON response directly, instead of storing the JSON response as a file.

Here's a sample that you can try out. This uses https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com as its endpoint sample.

```dart
test('Test http', () async {
    final file = await http.get(Uri.parse('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/1'));
  final json = jsonDecode(file.body.toString());
  print('json contents: $json');
  print('userId: ${json['userId']}');
  final userId = json['userId'];
  expect(userId, 1);
});
```