# How to add image in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am developing Flutter app for the first time. I have an issue adding an image. I have a following questions:

1. Where to create an images folder?
2. Where to add assets tag in pubspec.ymal?
3. Is there any assets folder needed for this?

**What I tried:**

```
 assets:
    - images/lake.jpg
```

inside pubspec.ymal :

Full file :

```
name: my_flutter_app
description: A new Flutter application.

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true,
  assets:
    - images/lake.jpg
```

**Error log :**

```
#/properties/flutter/properties/uses-material-design: type: wanted [boolean] got true,
Error detected in pubspec.yaml:
Error building assets

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/home/abc/Downloads/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 435

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:flutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command '/home/abc/Downloads/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Finished with error: Gradle build failed: 1
```

**My main.dart code :**

```
// Copyright 2017 The Chromium Authors. All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
// found in the LICENSE file.

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
// Uncomment lines 7 and 10 to view the visual layout at runtime.
//import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart' show debugPaintSizeEnabled;

void main() {
  //debugPaintSizeEnabled = true;
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget titleSection = new Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
      child: new Row(
        children: [
          new Expanded(
            child: new Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                new Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
                  child: new Text(
                    'Oeschinen Lake Campground',
                    style: new TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                new Text(
                  'Kandersteg, Switzerland',
                  style: new TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.grey[500],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          new Icon(
            Icons.star,
            color: Colors.red[500],
          ),
          new Text('41'),
        ],
      ),
    );

    Column buildButtonColumn(IconData icon, String label) {
      Color color = Theme.of(context).primaryColor;

      return new Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          new Icon(icon, color: color),
          new Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
            child: new Text(
              label,
              style: new TextStyle(
                fontSize: 12.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                color: color,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      );
    }

    Widget buttonSection = new Container(
      child: new Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: [
          buildButtonColumn(Icons.call, 'CALL'),
          buildButtonColumn(Icons.near_me, 'ROUTE'),
          buildButtonColumn(Icons.share, 'SHARE'),
        ],
      ),
    );

    Widget textSection = new Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
      child: new Text(
        '''
Lake Oeschinen lies at the foot of the Blüemlisalp in the Bernese Alps. Situated 1,578 meters above sea level, it is one of the larger Alpine Lakes. A gondola ride from Kandersteg, followed by a half-hour walk through pastures and pine forest, leads you to the lake, which warms to 20 degrees Celsius in the summer. Activities enjoyed here include rowing, and riding the summer toboggan run.
        ''',
        softWrap: true,
      ),
    );

    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text('Top Lakes'),
        ),
        body: new ListView(
          children: [
            new Image.asset(
              'images/lake.jpg',
              width: 600.0,
              height: 240.0,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
            titleSection,
            buttonSection,
            textSection,
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I am referring to this tutorial **https://flutter.io/tutorials/layout/**

Also, I want to ask if there are any tools for a clean rebuild in a flutter as I can't find any options for this.

Comment: your title too generic misleading many to here including me? mind changing it?

Comment: https://youtu.be/70G_XbpEyYk watch this

Comment: Huge thx the official documentation - very crealy! Nobody doesn't know where to place their images

Answer (score 94, accepted):

I think the error is caused by the redundant `,`

```yaml
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true, # <<< redundant , at the end of the line
  assets:
    - images/lake.jpg
```

I'd also suggest to create an `assets` folder in the directory that contains the `pubspec.yaml` file and move `images` there and use

```yaml
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/images/lake.jpg
```

The `assets` directory will get some additional IDE support that you won't have if you put assets somewhere else.

Comment: Thank you sir for reply.. I have created assets directory and inside that created images directory and out an image inside it.. also removed "," .. but now getting this error `No file or variants found for asset: images/lake.jpg.`

Comment: You still need to add `assets` directory to the file path `asset: assets/images/lake.jpg`

Comment: Sir i have one more query.. as I have done one demo in main.dart and successfully completed it.. now i am making another demo in the same file by removing previous code.. i got an output of that new demo but now when i check app from apk it is showing first demo instead the current one.. is there anything i am doing wrong?

Comment: You might need to run `flutter clean` to make `flutter run` or `flutter build` take up changes. I think the Flutter team is aware of the issue and it happens quite frequently, but I can't tell if they can fix it soon.

Comment: where i can find this options flutter clean /flutter run/flutter build ? as in build i am getting only one option analyze apk...

Comment: You need to execute it in a command line shell in your Flutter project directory (where `pubspec.yaml` is)

Comment: What is that additional IDE support you mentioned?

Comment: Autocompletion when you refer to assets in code, bit no progress since.

Comment: i'm intrigued on what are the additional IDE supports one wouldn't have if the images aren't in the "assets" directory

Comment: What other autocompletion are you referring to? There's already autocompletion and file name is a string so it wont be picked up anyways.

Answer (score 340):

## How to include images in your app

#### 1. Create an `assets/images` folder

- This should be located in the root of your project, in the same folder as your `pubspec.yaml` file.
- In Android Studio you can right click in the Project view
- You don't have to call it `assets` or `images`. You don't even need to make `images` a subfolder. Whatever name you use, though, is what you will register in the `pubspec.yaml` file.

#### 2. Add your image to the new folder

- You can just copy your image into `assets/images`. The relative path of `lake.jpg`, for example, would be `assets/images/lake.jpg`.

#### 3. Register the assets folder in `pubspec.yaml`

- Open the `pubspec.yaml` file that is in the root of your project.
- Add an `assets` subsection to the `flutter` section like this:

```yaml
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/images/lake.jpg
```

- If you have multiple images that you want to include then you can leave off the file name and just use the directory name (include the final `/`):

```yaml
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/images/
```

***Note***: Make sure to use the *exact* number of spaces. That's **2** spaces per indentation.

#### 4. Use the image in code

- Get the asset in an Image widget with `Image.asset('assets/images/lake.jpg')`.
- The entire `main.dart` file is here:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Image from assets"),
        ),
        body: Image.asset('assets/images/lake.jpg'), //   <--- image
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

#### 5. Restart your app

When making changes to *pubspec.yaml* I find that I often need to completely stop my app and restart it again, especially when adding assets. Otherwise I get a crash.

Running the app now you should have something like this:

[image]

## Further reading

- See the [documentation](https://flutter.io/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images#loading-images) for how to do things like provide alternate images for different densities.

## Videos

The first video here goes into a lot of detail about how to include images in your app. The second video covers more about how to adjust how they look.

- [Flutter Tutorial - 1/2 Image - Deep Dive](https://youtu.be/JDDoN2THwug)
- [Flutter Tutorial - 2/2 Image - Deep Dive](https://youtu.be/7HoEsLvvRPg)

Answer (score 34):

1. Create `images` folder in root level of your project.

   [image]

   [image]
2. Drop your image in this folder, it should look like

   [image]
3. Go to your `pubspec.yaml` file, add `assets` header and pay close attention to all the spaces.

   ```
   flutter:

     uses-material-design: true

     # add this
     assets:
       - images/profile.jpg
   ```
4. Tap on `Packages get` at the top right corner of the IDE.

   [image]
5. Now you can use your image anywhere using

   ```
   Image.asset("images/profile.jpg")
   ```

Answer (score 12):

To use image in Flutter. Do these steps.

**1.** Create a ***Directory*** inside assets folder named **images**. As shown in figure below[image]

**2.** Put your desired images to images folder.

**3.** Open ***pubpsec.yaml*** file . And add declare your images.Like:--[image]

**4.** Use this images in your code as.

```
  Card(
            elevation: 10,
              child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.orangeAccent,
              image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage("assets/images/dropbox.png"),
          fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
          alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
          ),
          ),
          child: Text("$index",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red,fontSize: 16,fontFamily:'LangerReguler')),
                alignment: Alignment.center,
          ),
          );
```

Answer (score 11):

The problem is in your `pubspec.yaml`, here you need to delete the last comma.

```
uses-material-design: true,
```

Comment: And also make sure assets: is aligned with uses-material-design

Answer (score 10):

**An alternative way to put images in your app** *(for me it just worked that way):*

1 - Create an assets/images folder

2 - Add your image to the new folder

3 - Register the assets folder in pubspec.yaml

**4 - Use this code:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    var assetsImage = new AssetImage('assets/images/mountain.jpg'); //<- Creates an object that fetches an image.
    var image = new Image(image: assetsImage, fit: BoxFit.cover); //<- Creates a widget that displays an image.

    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Climb your mountain!"),
          backgroundColor: Colors.amber[600], //<- background color to combine with the picture :-)
        ),
        body: Container(child: image), //<- place where the image appears
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Climb your mountain!]

Answer (score 9):

Create your assets directory the same as lib level

like this

```
projectName
 -android
 -ios
 -lib
 -assets
 -pubspec.yaml
```

then your pubspec.yaml like

```
  flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/images/
```

now you can use `Image.asset("/assets/images/")`

Answer (score 7):

*Follow Below Steps* **One OR Multiple** Image Insertion:

```
-> Create 'assets/images' folder as in project module.
-> put images which you want.
-> use of image using this syntax. ex.
            - Image.asset('assets/images/tony.jpg')

-> use image avatar which you want like, circle, square and much more as your need.
-> Open 'pubspec.yaml' file
-> write the code in 'flutter:' section. ex.
   -------------------------------
   uses-material-design: true
   assets:
    - assets/images/             // if multiple images you have then
    - assets/images/imagename.extension     // if single images you have then
   -------------------------------
-> click on 'PUB GET' button which occurs on Right side of Screen above.
-> Run App.
-> if you get any issue then 
-> Go to file -> Invalid caches/Restart -> Invalid Caches/Restart button
-> Done.
```

See Below Images to Get a Better idea of Implementation.

```
   •• Here, add image file like below. ••
```

[image]

```
   •• Here, add image file Description in PUBSPEC.YAML file like below. ••
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

When you adding assets directory in pubspec.yaml file give more attention in to spaces

this is wrong

```
flutter:
   assets:
    - assets/images/lake.jpg
```

This is the correct way,

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/images/
```

Comment: Whao! I was getting an error until I tried your answer. The devil is truly in the details. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

their is no need to create asset directory and under it images directory and then you put image.
Better is to just create Images directory inside your project where pubspec.yaml exist and put images inside it 
and access that images just like as shown in tutorial/documention

assets:
    - images/lake.jpg // inside pubspec.yaml

Answer (score 2):

If the image is inside a package dependency, you should also provide the package name, event if you are referencing the image from the same dependency!

```dart
Image.asset("assets/pics/events_empty.png", package: "ui_elements"),
```

Ref:
[Asset images in package dependencies](http://%20Asset%20images%20in%20package%20dependencies)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you create the assets folder in the main directory, not in the `lib` folder.

[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

you can rather use this to see access to everything inside assets, because there may be folders like images, logo, icon, etc...

create the assets folder in the root of the project

```
MyProject
    android
    assets
    ios
    lib
    test
    web
    windows
    .gitignore
    pubspec.yaml
```

and in your pubspec.yaml, there are

```
assets:
#   - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
#  - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg
```

replace the last two lines by the 'assets/' to be able to directly access everything inside assets

- if you have directly images in assets

  ```
  assets:
    - assets/
  ```
- or if you have sub folders in assets

  ```
  assets:
    - assets/folder1/
    - assets/folder2/
    - assets/folder3/
  ```

Answer (score 1):

1. Create an assets/images folder and  Add your image to the folder

[image]

2. Register the assets folder in pubspec.yaml

   flutter:
   assets:
   - assets/images/placeholder_circle_image.png

If you have multiple images

```
  flutter:
    assets:
      - assets/images/
```

[image]

3. Use the image in code

   Image.asset(
   'assets/images/item_entry/add_car_video.png',
   width: 100,
   height: 100,
   fit: BoxFit.cover,
   cacheWidth:100 * MediaQuery.of(context).devicePixelRatio.round(),
   ),

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1- Create a new folder inside your application.

name it for example ‘images’

2- Drag and drop your picture inside the ‘images’ folder.

3- Go to your pubspec.yml file, put the path of your image in the assets section.

for example the name of the picture is 'FlutterImage'
write it like this:

assets:

- assets/images/FlutterImage.jpg

*Note:
The pubspec.yml file is very sensitve of any space, So type your code correctly to avoid errors.

4- insert the image code in your base code

Image.asset('assets/images/FlutterImage.jpg'),

Happy coding :)

Answer (score -2):

Error when comma is at the end of below line

```
uses-material-design: true,
```

[image]

when the line after `assets:` indent is not correct it throws below error

[image]

If the indent is corrected as shown in below, then error is fixed.

[image]

If the asset file is not added then it highlights that with yellowish background but `Pub get` doesn't throw error but there will be an error during installation.

In short, Code Indent and syntax is important

You can create a folder and reference it as shown