# Leading Image overflows in ListTile

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-image

I have a `ListView` with `ListTile`. Each `ListTile` has a `title` with `Text`, `subtitle` with `Text`, and `leading` with an `Image`.

Now, the Image is too big and vertically stretches into the next row, overlapping the Image there.

How can I make sure that the Image stays within the bounds?

EDIT:

I’d like not to give the image a fixed size, but rather let it adjust to the height of the list tile as given by title+subtitle’s intrinsic height.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

[image: Result]

You should use `CircleAvatar` as `leading` in your `ListTile`. It has a `radius` property also that you can change, if you wish.

```dart
leading: CircleAvatar(
  backgroundImage: AssetImage("..."), // No matter how big it is, it won't overflow
),
```

---

[image: Result]

If you wanna use rectangle image, you can use

```dart
leading: ConstrainedBox(
  constraints: BoxConstraints(
    minWidth: 44,
    minHeight: 44,
    maxWidth: 64,
    maxHeight: 64,
  ),
  child: Image.asset(profileImage, fit: BoxFit.cover),
),
```

Comment: Do we also have a BoxAvatar?

Comment: NO there is no BoxAvatar, the other option you can use `ConstrainedBox` and give it min/max width/height according to your needs.

Comment: Hi, im having "FlutterError (Unable to load asset: http/www.blabla......." exception while trying to use it.  I got the same exception in [Harsh Bhikadia](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55642120/16002501) solution. Do you know what it could cause it?

Comment: @Tim's You may want to take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57229784/6618622) answer on how to add image to your project.

Answer (score 8):

Do this:

```dart
leading: SizedBox(
  height: 100.0,
  width: 100.0, // fixed width and height
  child: Image.asset(...)
)
```

Comment: I’d like to make the image adjust to the height of the Title+Subtitle.

Comment: The Image itself also has a fit : BoxFit property that didn’t work. Why should FittedBox be better?