# How to solve the leading overflow problem in ListTile?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm having `leading` overflow issues with `ListTile`:

```
Leading widget consumes entire tile width. Please use a sized widget, or consider replacing ListTile with a custom widget (see https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ListTile-class.html#material.ListTile.4)

'package:flutter/src/material/list_tile.dart':

package:flutter/…/material/list_tile.dart:1

Failed assertion: line 1204 pos 7: 'tileWidth != leadingSize.width || tileWidth == 0.0'
```

How can I solve it?

I referred to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55641880/16124033) and tried the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55648892/16124033). However, I still get the same error.

My code:

```dart
ListTile(
  leading: CircleAvatar(
    radius: 17.5,
    maxRadius: 17.5,
    minRadius: 17.5,
    backgroundColor: Colors.cyan,
    child: const Icon(
      Icons.timer_outlined,
      color: Colors.white,
    ),
  ),
  minLeadingWidth: 0.0,
  title: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    children: [
      Text(
        …,
        style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.cyan, fontSize: 16.0),
      ),
      Text(
        …,
        maxLines: 1,
        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
        style: TextStyle(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 117, 117, 117), fontSize: 16.0 * 0.8),
      ),
    ],
  ),
  …
),
```

Feel free to leave a comment if you need more information.

How to solve the `leading` overflow problem in `ListTile`? I would appreciate any help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Kindly share what is error?

Comment: Hi @MobinAnsar thanks for your reply! I shared the error in my question (`Leading widget consumes entire tile width...`)

Comment: You are Always welcome! Check my Answer I will Solve this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Just need to Remove:

> ```
> maxRadius: 17.5,
> minRadius: 17.5,
> ```

```
 ListTile(
      leading: CircleAvatar(
        radius: 17.5,
        backgroundColor: Colors.cyan,
        child: const Icon(
          Icons.timer_outlined,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
      minLeadingWidth: 0.0,
      title: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
        Text(
        "abc",
        style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.cyan, fontSize: 16.0),
      ),
      Text("aa",
      maxLines: 1,
      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
      style: TextStyle(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 117, 117, 117), fontSize: 16.0 * 0.8),
),
],
),
),
```

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer! Sadly, the error doesn't go away

Comment: But it's working fine for me

Comment: @MyCar Check i will add image this is working fine for me

Comment: I share some other code. Can you try the code?

Comment: yes i also update my Answer please Check

Comment: You also don't get any errors?

Comment: No It's Working Fine For me I Also update image

Comment: My `ListTile` has a `subtitle` which is a `Column`. In my `Column` I have `Text` and `Row` contains multiple `Text`. Can you try the data structure I'm talking about?

Comment: Yes!i check all of your Requirement And solve your problem Also Paste Code and image as well

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the emulator just now. It works in the emulator, but the debug console still has errors. Why?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251432/discussion-between-mobin-ansar-and-my-car).