# I have a problem adding an image to a flutter project

Tags: web, flutter, dart

I am experimenting with a flutter web project (might not make a difference but worth mentioning), i want to add an image but i get an error every time i try,

I have added the right assets to the pubspec.yaml file and the files are in the folder.

i have tried restarting my ide, and flutter clean.
There was no change at all.

```dart
class _homePageState extends State<homePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var textStyle = TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontSize: 30,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w100,
                );
                
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        fontFamily: "MontSerrat"
      ),

      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.grey[400],
          title: Text("Example",
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
              fontSize: 40,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w100,
            ),
          )
        ),
        body: 
        Container(
          color: Colors.grey[400],
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Image.asset('assets/images/first_image.jpg')
            ],
          ),
        )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

the pubspec.yaml looks like:

```
name: epq_webapp
description: An app built using Flutter for web

environment:
  # You must be using Flutter >=1.5.0 or Dart >=2.3.0
  sdk: '>=2.3.0-dev.0.1 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter_web: any
  flutter_web_ui: any

dev_dependencies:
  build_runner: ^1.4.0
  build_web_compilers: ^2.0.0
  pedantic: ^1.0.0

dependency_overrides:
  flutter_web:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/flutter/flutter_web
      path: packages/flutter_web
  flutter_web_ui:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/flutter/flutter_web
      path: packages/flutter_web_ui

flutter:
  fonts:
  - family: MontSerrat
    fonts:
      - asset: assets\fonts\montserrat\Montserrat-Regular.ttf

  assets:
    - assets/
    - assets/images/first_image.jpg
```

i expect my code to display an image, however i get an error message,

Unable to load asset: assets/images/first_image.jpg

Comment: 1 - So have you try just define the path in your Image.asset('images/a_dot_burr.jpeg')
without the assets folder? 2 - Are you sure that you have this assets folder inside of lib base folder?

Comment: Mind to edit your question with your `pubspec.yaml` please?

Answer (score 0):

Flutter uses the pubspec.yaml file, located at the root of your project, to identify assets required by an app.

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/my_icon.png
    - assets/background.png
```

make sure you have your image in the assets directory

then

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  // ...
  return DecoratedBox(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      image: DecorationImage(
        image: AssetImage('assets/background.png'),
        // ...
      ),
      // ...
    ),
  );
  // 
}
```

You should get your image rendered

Answer (score 0):

update your `pubspec.yaml` with this

`

```
  fonts:
  - family: MontSerrat
    fonts:
      - asset: assets\fonts\montserrat\Montserrat-Regular.ttf

  uses-material-design: true <--- line added ---
  assets:
    - assets/
    - assets/images/first_image.jpg
```

you could also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50903106/add-image-in-flutter-app) it might help you out

Comment: Please checkout, [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50903106/add-image-in-flutter-app) a similar issue was raised

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by putting the assets under the web folder instead of the root of the project. then used

```
Image.asset(filename)
```

to display them.

Answer (score 0):

Pubspec.yaml should be like:

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/images/
```

Code Snippet:

```
Center(
              child: Image.asset(
                'assets/images/account.png',
                width: heartbeatAnimation.value,
                height: heartbeatAnimation.value,
              ),
            )
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using `flutter pub get`. It will save you time restarting andoid studio