# Project gets hang while uploading image in flutter project

Tags: image, flutter, dart

File where I want to load image

```
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
          height: 250,
          child: Card(
            child: Image.asset(
              '../../assets/images/person.jpg',
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
            ),
            elevation: 5,
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

pubspec.yaml

```
 # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
 assets:
  - assets/images/person.jpg
  - assets/images/burger.jpg
```

I have used `flutter clean` command also, i get image for once then after adding more images my project stuck. Unable to solve this problem. 
[image: This is happening for]
Suggestion would be appreciated?

Comment: Remove `../../` from asset name

Comment: I would also recommnd using just `- assets/images/` without file name in pubspec to include whole folder and get hot reloading when you add new images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bro you define wrong Image paths in `pubspec.yaml` file

define this way :

```
 assets:
   - assets/images/
```

for more info try out

[this](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images)

or

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50903106/how-to-add-image-in-flutter)

and In your `.dart` file define this way :

```
Image.asset('assets/images/person.jpg'),
```