# 'Unable to load asset error' is caught by 'Image resource service'

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, pubspec

**The Error:**

======= Exception caught by image resource service ================================================
The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
Unable to load asset: images/google-logo.png

## When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      PlatformAssetBundle.load (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:227:7)

#1      AssetBundleImageProvider._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:667:14)

Image provider: AssetImage(bundle: null, name: "images/google-logo.png")
Image key: AssetBundleImageKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#36c1f(), name: "images/google-logo.png", scale: 1.0)

**My 'pubspec.yaml' file:**

```
'''flutter:
     uses-material-design: true
     assets:
        - images/facebook-logo.png
        - images/google-logo.png '''
```

I am loading the image into the page using the following code:
**IN 'sign in page.dart' file:**

```
'''CustomRaisedButton(
            child: Image.asset('images/google-logo.png'),
            color: Colors.white,
            onPressed: () {},
          ),'''
```

Comment: Have you added your assets folder inside `pubspec.yaml`? You can follow this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50903106/how-to-add-image-in-flutter

Comment: @ChiragBargoojar I did add assets folder inside the 'pubspec.yaml' file.

Comment: Can your share your `pubspec.yaml` and where you created your assets folder?

Answer (score 2):

First set your image path in **pubspec.yaml** file's `assets` propety, Uncomment it and write path for you image folder like.,

```
flutter:

[2 whitespaces or 1 tab]assets:
[4 whitespaces or 2 tabs]- assets/images/ #path of your image folder
```

Do `pub get` once, and can use the images from given path folder.

If your problem is not resolved yet. I think your assets are not loading, use Following commands in terminal,

`flutter clean`
`flutter pub get`

Restart or Reinstall the application.

Comment: Thanks.It was an indentation problem. SOLVED

Comment: Thanks! I missed assets/ on the second line

Answer (score 0):

Specify Image path as follows

```
Image.asset("assets/images/car_android.png")
```

OR

```
Image(image: AssetImage("assets/images/car_android.png"))
```

The problem is flutter can't recognize where your image is exactly stored.

If the problem continues then try to do HOT RESTART this will solve your problem.

If you update pubspec.yaml file then run `flutter pub get` to update the libraries if your IDE doesn't update it automatically.