# Add different icons in Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I am developing my own app in Flutter and I want to use some icons that I've made from my own.
I have used some of the icons provided by *font_awesome_flutter* but at this point of my code I would like to add some other icons ( svgs or pngs) which are not included in this package to make it more personal.

This is how my app organization it is: 
[Code organization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35nU7.png)

And that is the part of the code where I want to implement my own picture *upct.png*:

```
    class _Encabezado extends StatelessWidget {
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        IconHeader(
          icon: FontAwesomeIcons.glasses, 
          //icon2: FontAwesomeIcons.university, 
          icon2: SvgPicture.asset('assets/svgs/upct.svg'),
          titulo: 'UPCT VR 360 EXPERIENCE', 
          subtitulo: 'Universidad Politécnica de Cartagena',
          color1: Color(0xff536CF6),
          color2: Color(0xff66A9F2),
        ),
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add image in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50903106/how-to-add-image-in-flutter)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use local asset folder images need to add the base path in `pubspec.yaml`

Example:

```
flutter:

  assets:
    - assets/svgs/
```

Note: add base path under `flutter`

Comment: I have this added, but appears me an error when I try to implement in the terms as I have done

Comment: can you please share the error that you are getting?

Comment: @IgnacioCastellanosMoreno not able to see your error....can you post it? or update the error in the question

Answer (score 0):

For SVGs
Use https://www.fluttericon.com to convert your SVGs into a font file, download the result folder and import the font in your `pubspec.yaml`

```
flutter:
  fonts:
    - family:  MyFlutterApp
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/MyFlutterApp.ttf
```

Comment: I have done the fluttericon folder, and I had an assets folder into the project, should I place it there or in another path? Because I am getting  a pubspec.yaml error. Thanks!!

Comment: What error are you getting ? I just updated the code to have the right spaces so try again

Comment: The thing is that I dont know really well where I should put the fodler that I have created.  If you see the first image that i posted, in which level of folders should I place it? Because I put in my `pubspec.yaml` what you wrote but I didn't obtain anything, I cannot import it, or I don't know where it goes