# How to add images in pubspec.yaml file

Tags: flutter

Expected a key while parsing a block mapping.
|
66|     - images/
|     ^
|
Please correct the pubspec.yaml file at pubspec.yaml
exit code 1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add image in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50903106/how-to-add-image-in-flutter)

Comment: Can you include your `pubspec.yaml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `pubspec.yaml` file under scroll down to `flutter` section and add your assets like this:

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - image_path/image_name
```