# I couldn't display an image in Dart

Tags: flutter, image, dart, pubspec

I am trying to display a picture but it didn't work well.

[image: 2]

[image: 1]

Comment: Can you include your code-snippet instead of code-image? and what is `ImageOrnekleri()`

Comment: ı couldn't do snippet and also ImageOrnekleri()'s means(Ornekleri is turkısh )    ImageExamples()

Comment: It is ok, but you need to include code-snippet in dart that will reproduce the error.  More about [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: ı installed but didn't work now. my error is    Exception caught by services library

Comment: That is ok, Consider including error message with code-snippet(no code-image). More about [asking good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: thank you and ı want something from you. when ı tried to run my program again,there were not any errror but there is a page which is image_provider.dart  is appears in my screen and rethrow is filled yellow.ı am so confused.Whatever you say ı can show it is not problem

Comment: *rethrow is filled yellow* could be overflow issue. cant say for sure

Comment: what should ı show you to understand the error

Comment: You can include sample  code-snippet and error message, if on UI include an image of output on question, then I might be able to get it

Comment: ı included it..

Comment: Sorry not like this, code-snippet means the code you've written on VS Code.  try to follow those previous links or others upvoted question

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you're looking for.

```
        body: Center(
        child: Image.network(
        'https://docs.flutter.dev/assets/images/dash/dash-fainting.gif', width: 200, height: 200,),
        ),
```

Here is the complete code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
  title: 'Home',
  home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Image ornekleri')),
    body: Center(
      child: Image.network(
        'https://docs.flutter.dev/assets/images/dash/dash-fainting.gif', width: 200, height: 200,),
    ),
  ),
);
}
}
```

You can use Image.asset() if you have local image files [as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50903106/how-to-add-image-in-flutter)

Comment: ı didn't take the image on the web I had already have it

Comment: you can use Image.asset() according to the method mentioned in the link in my answer.

Comment: If you are running your application in `Release Mode` make sure to add `Internet Permission` in `Manifest File`