# how can I add assets in flutter pubspec.yaml

Tags: flutter, dart, assets, flutter-pubspec

[image: this is the error that has appeared]

I tried to just add (assets/ ) but that didn't solve the problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add image in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50903106/how-to-add-image-in-flutter)

Comment: can you show us your assets folder?

Answer (score 0):

The assets to specify in the pubspec should be inside the `flutter` section.

```yaml
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/my_icon.png
    - assets/background.png
```

also example with directories:

```yaml
flutter:
  assets:
    - directory/
    - directory/subdirectory/
```

*Take a fast read to the official docs: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/assets-and-images*

Comment: No need to specify each and every assets.
Checkout my answers

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps

1. Create a new Folder name "assets" parallel to Lib folder
2. Create a folder name "images" in it.
3. Define a assets like a below in a "pubspec.yaml"

   assets:

   - assets/images/
4. Use it like a below

   Image.asset("assets/images/my-profile.png"),