# I cant upload a image in flutter

Tags: flutter

Good day,
Im trying to upload a image to flutter but i cannot see whats wrong with my code.
any help will be highly appreciated.
thank you
this is image of my file system

[image]

[image: file system]

and here the error a get
[![enter image description here][3]][3]

and if you want to try my code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Dashboard extends StatelessWidget {
  const Dashboard({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30.0, horizontal: 40),
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: const [
                        Text('Hi Emma', style:TextStyle(fontSize: 30),),
                        Text('Welcome back', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40),),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Image.asset('assets/images/pic.png')
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

the error

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 14 Pro Max in debug mode...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           16.7s
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:64299/4VQyTtoPAoU=/ws
Syncing files to device iPhone 14 Pro Max...

======== Exception caught by image resource service ================================================
The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
Unable to load asset: assets/images/pic.png.

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      PlatformAssetBundle.loadBuffer (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:288:7)
#1      AssetBundleImageProvider._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:731:35)
#2      AssetBundleImageProvider.loadBuffer (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:695:14)
#3      ImageProvider.resolveStreamForKey.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:513:13)
#4      ImageCache.putIfAbsent (package:flutter/src/painting/image_cache.dart:384:22)
#5      ImageProvider.resolveStreamForKey (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:511:81)
#6      ScrollAwareImageProvider.resolveStreamForKey (package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_aware_image_provider.dart:106:19)
#7      ImageProvider.resolve.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:358:9)
#8      ImageProvider._createErrorHandlerAndKey.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:473:24)
<asynchronous suspension>
Image provider: AssetImage(bundle: null, name: "assets/images/pic.png")
Image key: AssetBundleImageKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#9da8b(), name: "assets/images/pic.png", scale: 1.0)
====================================================================================================
```

Comment: In your pubspec.yaml, specify the subfolder as well -assets/images/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add image in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50903106/how-to-add-image-in-flutter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add it at pubspec.yaml file. then stop application and run again.

```
 assets:
    - assets/images/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/icons/
    - assets/fonts/
    - assets/images/
```

Just add `images/` after `assets`

Answer (score 0):

Image.asset('assets/images/pic.png')

to

```
Image.asset('lib/assets/images/pic.png')
```

and check the  pubspec.yaml file too that you added the file there or not if not added kindly add 1st then do it .