# How to read and write a text file in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, text-files

How do you read text from a file and write text to a file?

I've been learning about how to read and write text to and from a file. I found another question about [reading from assets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44816042/flutter-read-text-file-from-assets), but that is not the same. I will add my answer below from what I learned from the documentation.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

## Setup

Add the following plugin in `pubspec.yaml`:

```yaml
dependencies:
  path_provider: ^1.6.27
```

Update the version number to whatever is [current](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/path_provider).

And import it in your code.

```dart
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
```

You also have to import `dart:io` to use the `File` class.

```dart
import 'dart:io';
```

## Writing to a text file

```dart
_write(String text) async {
  final Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  final File file = File('${directory.path}/my_file.txt');
  await file.writeAsString(text);
}
```

## Reading from a text file

```dart
Future<String> _read() async {
  String text;
  try {
    final Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final File file = File('${directory.path}/my_file.txt');
    text = await file.readAsString();
  } catch (e) {
    print("Couldn't read file");
  }
  return text;
}
```

## Notes

- You can also get the path string with `join(directory.path, 'my_file.txt')` but you need to import `'package:path/path.dart'`.
- [Flutter's Official Documentation of Reading and Writing Files](https://flutter.io/docs/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files)
- This works for iOS, Android, Linux and MacOS but not for web.

Comment: I used _read function But I get this problem: "The function 'File' isn't defined."

Comment: @Heyran.rs You need to import `dart:io`. In Android Studio you can put the cursor on `File` and press Option+Return in Mac or Alt+Enter in Linux/Windows to add it automatically from a menu.

Comment: Thank you. Now I get another problem. It returns "Couldn't read file". My assets is: <- data/table.txt>. I only replace  my_file.txt  to  table.txt   in _read methode.

Comment: @Heyran.rs, I'm not sure why. I can only suggest that you step through in debugging mode and try to isolate where the error is. Also, print the error message in the catch block. If you still can't solve it, then try asking a new question with all these details included.

Comment: How to know where this my_file is stored? Can I access it manually?

Comment: Is it possible to change the storage location, because what if I want to run this on linux or web? Actually I did try, and it crashes, because `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory` works only for android and iOS by accessing to their local folders. I wonder if there's a way to change the root folder for the new directory.

Comment: @IvánYoed, good question. I haven't done this yet. If you find the answer please leave a comment or another answer.

Comment: Sure, I think this could be a solution. I'll be testing it myself to check if indeed it is https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider_linux. It implements the package:path_provider functionality for linux.

Comment: As I intended to, I tested the `path_provider` package on Linux. I confirmed that this package has already support for it, so this "read and write" practice on flutter for desktop on linux does work. The crash was on flutter for web. By the way, the directory for the created `.txt` in my case was at Documents.

Comment: @IvánYoed, Thank you for the updates. I also added a note to my answer.

Comment: I do have a question and maybe you've already occupied yourself with this topic. I share with you the post, related to the same features named in your post. Here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66394148/flutter-delete-certain-amount-of-characters-of-a-txt-file

Comment: @IvánYoed, sorry, I'm not sure. I don't have time to work on it right now.

Comment: No worries. I'll keep it up with my research and as soon as I find something, I'll be sharing it with the community.

Comment: I couldn't get the file write to work at first, it only ever seemed to write a single line to the file when called multiple times in a loop. Then I realised I was missing the await keyword from the line "await file.writeAsString". For some reason it doesn't work correctly without using await - maybe there's some file locking going on or something and it trips over itself.

Answer (score 6):

As additional info to @Suragch's answer, if you want to find the file you created, you can do as the images show:

[image]

And then inside that data folder, go again to a folder named data and search for your package, and then go to:

[image]

If you happen to create new files, in order to be able to see them, just right click and click `Synchronize`.

[image]

Comment: If you don't see *Device File Explorer* you can check the Event Log and see if you can configure Android Framework based on your AndroidManifest.xml files, after this, you will see *Device File Explorer* under _View -> Tools Windows_

Answer (score 0):

An another way to pull the file from the device is by using adb pull command. You can find the file path by debugging the code and then use adb pull command. adb is located in Android SDK -> platform-tools directory.

```
./adb pull /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.innovate.storage.storage_sample/files/sample.txt ~/Downloads
```

Answer (score 0):

@Suragch 's answer is right. Except the version of `path_provider` that you want to use now is:

`path_provider: ^2.0.9`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31690527)