# How to open/read file(.doc/.pdf/.txt etc) in text view using Flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to let user open file's content into this `TextView`

```
child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Text('**THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO LOAD OPENED FILES**'
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54122851/8101634

Comment: see this link you will get an idea after that also if you need help then reply back

Comment: [Reading and Writing Files](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files)