# Saving database entries to text file (flutter)

Tags: flutter, sqlite, sqflite

I working on a diary sort of app in Flutter. Entries get saved in a DB. I'm now trying to figure out how I can save the entries to a Textfile. I have tried finding ways to go about that, but nothing so far that seems to fit my needs.

I want to be able to:

- save database entries to a text file on the device
- or put the entries as contents in an email.

If anyone can help me in the right direction, I would really appreciate it.

Cheers,

Comment: check if this works for you https://stackoverflow.com/a/54122851/10409567

Comment: Do you just want to convert your database records 1:1 into an CSV?

Comment: @griffins: Will need to take a further look; however for now it's still unclear to me how to pull the data from the database, and then follow the instructions you've linked to. I will check it out, thanks for the link!

Comment: @Superlokkus Well, csv is a start, but I want to be able to pull the data and send / store it a more legible format. Diary entries etc are not that easy to read in csv format. But, I'll take CSV if there are no other options.

Comment: Then there is already an option in SQLite: https://sqlite.org/cli.html

Comment: @Superlokkus Thanks! Think I found what is was looking for.