# See the whole length of a printed into console list

Tags: list, flutter, dart, console

I've printed a very long array (about 2k lenght) into console.
Unfortunately console cut it and I can't see the whole content, how can I see the entire list?
My purpose is to use the content into another file in the project.

Thanks all

Comment: Did you tried log() imported from dart.developer?

Comment: Is this on a mobile device?  Android and iOS limit the length of log messages. See https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/22665.

Comment: No, I didn't try to import log, how could I do this? And yes, It is on a mobile device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54122851/12103616 or

```
main() async {
  List letters = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k"];
  File file = new File("Letters.txt");
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    await file.writeAsString("${letters[i]}", mode: FileMode.append);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may take the array.toString() in a string variable and can check the length of the string. Now you can according to the length being printed on the console, print the subString(s) of that string using for loop. This might be one way.