# Is there a package with english names in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a simple question - is there any package with list of english names? I am looking for something like english_words package, but with names.
If there isn't such package could you provide me with some other ways to get a list of english names without just printing them all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if something like this packages exist but I have a idea that can solve your problem.
you can get a list of English names on Internet ([for example](https://www.familyeducation.com/baby-names/first-name/origin/english) and copy them into a txt file, read or write like other files on flutter (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54122850/how-to-read-and-write-a-text-file-in-flutter) for more detail)
Hope it helps