# How to assign value of Text Asset to String and display it in Text()?

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I want to modify data from a text asset (.txt file) with a function and display it in a `Text()` widget. `myFunction` Takes datatype `String` as parameter and return datatype `String`.

I've read the documentation. [Loading Asset from Image](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images#loading-text-assets), this didn't worked. I've also tried solution from [Suragch's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54133627/10854681).

This maybe is a case where I should use `FutureBuilder` but I'm not able to understand how to make it work here (I'm new). I'm going to use another function to modify the data from file and then display.

This is one of the things I tried:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  Future<String> aloadAsset(BuildContext context) async {
    return await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString('assets/help.txt');
  }

  String helps = myFunction(await aloadAsset(context));
  return Scaffold(
    body: Text(helps)
  );
}
```

When assigning value from `await aloadAsset(context)` to String, I get these errors: `Unexpected text 'await'.` & `A value of type 'Future<String>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'String'.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how to read the `text` from your file, you have to modify your `Build` function to include a `FutureBuilder`. Then you have to move the `aloadAsset` function out of the build:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return FutureBuilder(
      future: aloadAsset(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
        if(if(snapshot.hasData)){
            return Scaffold(
              body: Text(snapshot.data)
            );
        }
            return Scaffold(
              body: Text('No Available data') //This will be returned in case you didn't receive data yet or in the case of a file error.
            );
      }
}

Future<String> aloadAsset(BuildContext context) async {
     return await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString('assets/help.txt');

}
```

Comment: kindly explain `if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done)` vs `if(snapshot.hasData)`. Which is better to use?

Comment: for your case it is better to use the latter : if(snapshot.hasData) to handle the event of wrong file name or nonexistent one. I will edit the answer.

Comment: I am not the OP, just read your answer and wanted to clarify; thanks for the edit.

Comment: I know, and by the way thank you for notifying me for this issue which led me to correct my answer to suit the post case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you explain how can I assign the data from "assets/help.txt" file to a String?

Comment: You can define a class-level var and assign the value to it inside `aloadAsset()`

Answer (score 0):

`await` keyword can only be used in an `async` function. What you can do here is:
Make the widget as `StatefulWidget` and then in the state class:

```
String helps = "";
```

in the `initState()` method:

```
aloadAsset();
```

and change your function to:

```
aloadAsset() async {
    helps = myFunction(await rootBundle.loadString('assets/help.txt'));
    setState((){});
  }
```

Don't forget to add the import

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;
```