# Run some Javascript file like index.js in Flutter Webview

Tags: javascript, file, dart, flutter, package

how I can run Javascript file in the flutter_webview_plugin. I try it with this.

```
flutterWebViewPlugin.evalJavascript("require('./index.js');");
```

But nothing happens.

when I try to run flutter code it's shows nothing

my `index.Js` file contains a simple alert statement

```
alert('hello world');
```

Answer (score 2):

**First,** You used "require" function. this function is not implemented in javascript itself. [it's a part of NodeJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9901082/what-is-this-javascript-require). so that function will not work.

In order to load a js file into flutter, you should consider it as a text file and load it properly. So, you need to add the file to assets folder, add into pubspec file, then load it. [read the full answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54133627/3123267)

**Second,** you used evalJavascript. this function can be used in many different situations. but it will work only if you have a view panel.

Check below example:

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_webview_plugin/flutter_webview_plugin.dart';

main() async {
  String jsCode = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/javascript.js');

  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: LunchWebView(jsCode),
  ));
}

class LunchWebView extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  LunchWebView(this.text);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final FlutterWebviewPlugin flutterWebviewPlugin = FlutterWebviewPlugin();
    flutterWebviewPlugin.launch('https://www.google.com');
    flutterWebviewPlugin.evalJavascript(text);
    return Container();
  }
}
```

**NOTE:** :  I didn't handle reloading and other exceptions. you should check if there is any webview object open and then call Lunch method.