# Flutter: Unexpected character (at character 1)

Tags: json, parsing, flutter, dart

In Flutter, no matter what json file i try to decode I get the same above titled error. 
Originally I thought it was something with my project but after starting a new template Flutter project I still receive the same error. I have the json file in my root folder and have added them to the pubspec.yaml file:

```
  assets:
      - Sample-JSON-data.json
      - Sample-employee-JSON-data.json
```

Main.dart code at the moment:

```
    var jsonString = 'Sample-JSON-data.json';
    var response = jsonDecode(jsonString);
    print(response);
```

I have verified my json data on multiple test sites as well as tried various methods in the [Flutter Documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json). Json data:

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    151.0763783444317,
                    -33.98045132346684
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    151.07774912725728,
                    -33.97470462237792
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    151.07774912725728,
                    -33.97470462237792
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    151.07774912725728,
                    -33.97470462237792
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    151.0763783444317,
                    -33.98045132346684
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    151.07774912725728,
                    -33.97470462237792
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    151.07774912725728,
                    -33.97470462237792
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    151.07774912725728,
                    -33.97470462237792
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    151.0763783444317,
                    -33.98045132346684
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you are not loading the data from the json file.

Try:

```
var jsonString = await rootBundle.loadString('Sample-JSON-data.json')
```

Comment: Thanks, I've used this previously and I must have a case of fuzzy-brain so thank god you brought it up.

Answer (score 2):

`jsonDecode` expects an input to be valid JSON serialized into String fe. 
`{ "message": "Hello World!" }`. So this would work: `jsonDecode('{"message": "Hello World!"}')`.

What you are passing to it is a file name, it **won't** automatically read the file for you. You can check how to do that here:

[Flutter - Read text file from assets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44816042/flutter-read-text-file-from-assets)

Comment: Thanks, this was super helpful. I was misunderstanding the serialization.