# Can't Read file from the asset?

Tags: flutter, filesystems, flutter-dependencies

In my app, there is a button that will copy the file(in my case txt) to the local download folder. I even ask permission from the phone and it works. But when I read from the txt file, the error said

> FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = 'assets/readme.txt' (OS
> Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import "package:path_provider/path_provider.dart";
 
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
int a;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("What up"),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              await Permission.storage.request();
              if (PermissionStatus == PermissionStatus.granted) {
                print("permission granted");
              }
              if (PermissionStatus == PermissionStatus.denied) {
                print('permission denied');
              }
             var path = "assets/readme.txt";
             a = await readCounter();
             print(a);
            },
            child: Text("Press me"),
             
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


Future<int> readCounter() async {
  try {
    final file = File("assets/readme.txt");

    // Read the file.
    String contents = await file.readAsString();

    return int.parse(contents);
  } catch (e) {
    // If encountering an error, return 0.
    print(e);
  }
}
```

I add this code in android>app>src>main>AndroidMainfest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I also add the asset folder in pubspec.yaml

```
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/
```

Comment: Maybe you are looking for this ?? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44816042/flutter-read-text-file-from-assets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `File` class references a file in the whole file system of the device, not the assets of the application.

To access assets you should follow what is stated in the [documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images).

1. Import the flutter services `import 'package:flutter/services.dart'`
2. Use the `rootBundle` to access the `AssetBundle`
3. Use the `loadString` method to access the data inside your asset with the specified path `await rootBundle.loadString('assets/readme.txt');`

---

Implementation in your code:

```dart
Future<int> readCounter() async {
  try {
    String contents = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/readme.txt');

    return int.parse(contents);
  } catch (e) {
    // If encountering an error, return 0.
    print(e);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not put the text file in assets: just make it a dart file (.dart) that returns the contents and place it in lib, then work with it like other dart files.