# how to load local file in InAppWebView in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I want to load files from internal storage in In App WebView in flutter so that I can load that file in WebView.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can do that. Here are the steps:

See the example here, see how it uses HTML strings such as `kNavigationExamplePage`:
https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter/example

```
const String kNavigationExamplePage = '''
<!DOCTYPE html><html>
<head><title>Navigation Delegate Example</title></head>
<body>
<p>
The navigation delegate is set to block navigation to the youtube website.
</p>
<ul>
<ul><a href="https://www.youtube.com/">https://www.youtube.com/</a></ul>
<ul><a href="https://www.google.com/">https://www.google.com/</a></ul>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
''';

  Future<void> _onNavigationDelegateExample(
      WebViewController controller, BuildContext context) async {
    final String contentBase64 =
        base64Encode(const Utf8Encoder().convert(kNavigationExamplePage));
    await controller.loadUrl('data:text/html;base64,$contentBase64');
  }
```

What you need to do is to read this string from a File instead. This answer provides detailed steps on how to do that. Instead of a text file, you will read an HTML file. Later you will use it instead of the `kNavigationExamplePage` string.

[Flutter - Read text file from assets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44816042/flutter-read-text-file-from-assets)

**Edit:**
If you are using flutter_inappwebview, it seems it even has a function that uses your asset files directly: https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_inappwebview/latest/flutter_inappwebview/InAppWebViewController/loadFile.html

Comment: can we do that, in this plugin - InAppWebView?

Comment: Yes, please see my edit at the bottom of the answer. https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_inappwebview/latest/flutter_inappwebview/InAppWebViewController/loadFile.html

Comment: yes it's right, but I want to load it from internal storage instead of assets, can we do that?

Comment: yes https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_inappwebview/latest/flutter_inappwebview/InAppWebViewController/loadData.html

Comment: If this answer helped you please consider accepting it.

Comment: yes it's working thanks.

Comment: great, can you mark the answer as accepted using the tick icon next to it?

Answer (score 0):

```
 WebView(
          initialUrl: htmlToURI(code),
    ...
),


String htmlToURI(String code) {
  return Uri.dataFromString(code,
          mimeType: 'text/html', encoding: Encoding.getByName('utf-8'))
      .toString();
}
```

That was working in my case.