# How can I open and display an html file that has been stored locally on the device in Flutter Dart?

Tags: html, flutter, android-studio, dart, local-storage

I am writing an app in Flutter to run on Android and IOS Smart Phones. It will have a number of html files and .pngs that are stored locally (somewhere on the actual smartphone). When a text label is returned from an ML Image labeling capability in the app, I want it to open and display the html file that corresponds to the label. For example, if I photograph a car, the ML Image Labeller returns the label 'car', and the app then displays an html file called car.html (that is stored on the phone just in case of no internet access). The display of the .html file could be inside the app UI or launched as a separate webview.
I have played with url_launcher, inappwebview, and webview - but I do not know which is easiest for loading and opening a .html file stored locally on the device. Can anyone advise me, please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to load local file in InAppWebView in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71318428/how-to-load-local-file-in-inappwebview-in-flutter)

Comment: Thanks - this shows at least 2 different methods (the other method being inappwebview) - I am unsure which one to attempt as I am looking to implement best practice. Thankyou