# File not found issue in Flutter - pubspec.yaml file modified

Tags: flutter, dart, file

I'm out of ideas what can I do or what am I doing wrong. So I would like to read some words from a file saved in the assets folder:

[image]

I also modified the pubspec.yaml file:

```yaml
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/this.txt
```

My code looks like this:

```
 final String filePath = 'assets/this.txt';
 List<String> wordList = [];
    try {
      final file = File(filePath);
      List<String> lines = await file.readAsLines();
      final random = Random();
      for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        int randomIndex = random.nextInt(lines.length);
        wordList.add(lines[randomIndex]);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error reading file: $e');
    }
```

I still get the error code:

```
 Error reading file: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = 'assets/this.txt' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)
```

Ran out of ideas what I'm doing wrong :(

Comment: Duplicate of [Flutter - Read text file from assets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44816042/flutter-read-text-file-from-assets)

Answer (score -1):

The solution was using a method from the asset bundle.

```
List<String> wordList = [];
try {
      String fileContents = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/this.txt');
      fileContents = fileContents.toLowerCase();
      List<String> lines = fileContents.split('\n');
      final random = Random();
      for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        int randomIndex = random.nextInt(lines.length);
        wordList.add(lines[randomIndex]);
      }
 } catch (e) {
      print('Error reading file: $e');
 }
```